# XMLHTTPRequest resulting in Aw, snap in chrome

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome, three.js

I am making a server-based multiplayer game using three.js. The server is supposed to work like this

game-->Server2.php-->Server.txt

game-->Server.php-->Server.txt-->game

The way this works is

1.) Game is generated

2.) Each element is added to an array called sendtoserver

3.) sendtoserver is send via post to server2.php

4.) Server2.php writes sendtoserver to Server.txt

5.) The post request then opens a get request to server.php

6.) Server.php reads Server.txt and returns the results

However, chrome is running the request and giving an aw snaps error.
Here is the code

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Controls:
Up Arrow to Move Foward
Down Arrow to Move Backward
Left Arrow to Move Left
Right Arrow to Move Right
1 to Move Up
2 to Move Down
3 to Rotate Left
4 to Rotate Right
5 to Rotate Up
6 to Rotate Down










-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Rotating Cube</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Import three.js and jquery-->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r74/three.js">
        </script>
        <script src="jquery.js">
        </script>
        <!--Set up camera-->
        <script>
        var sendtoserver=["server:online"];
        getServerStatus=function(){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var response=xhttp.responseText;
            response=response.substring(0, response.indexOf('<'));
            alert(response);
            }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "Server.php", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
        turnserveron=function(){
        $.post( "Server2.php",{
          data:sendtoserver
        },function(){
        getServerStatus();
        });
        }
      Math.radians = function(degrees) {
            return degrees * Math.PI / 180;
            };
            function getrandomdirection(){
            return Math.radians(Math.round(Math.random()*360));
            }
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); 
            function render(){
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
            //some non-essential camera commands were deleted here
        function house(x,y,z,bodycolor1,bodycolor2,bodycolor3,roofcolor1,roofcolor2,roofcolor3,rotation){
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 3, 3 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color:"rgb("+bodycolor1+","+bodycolor2+","+bodycolor3+")" } );
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            var geometry2 = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0, 2.3, 4, 4, 1 );
            var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "rgb("+roofcolor1+","+roofcolor2+","+roofcolor3+")" } );
            var roof= new THREE.Mesh(geometry2,material2);
            cube.position.set(0+x,0+y,0+z);
            roof.position.set(0+x,3.5+y,0+z);
            roof.rotateY(0.7);





            var doorgeo=new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,2,1);
            var doormaterial=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xA52A2A});
            var door=new THREE.Mesh(doorgeo,doormaterial);
            door.position.set(0+x,-0.5+y,1+z)
                var house = new THREE.Object3D();
                house.add(cube);
                house.add(roof);
                house.add(door);
                scene.add(house);
                sendtoserver.push(house);
                //fix this
                house.rotateY(rotation);
            }
            renderer.setClearColor(0x00ffff, 1);
            var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "Grass.jpg" );
            texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            texture.repeat.set( 600, 600 );
            var groundmaterial=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
            var groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(400,400);
            ground=new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo,groundmaterial);
            ground.position.y = -1.9;
            ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
            ground.doubleSided=true;
            scene.add(ground);
            sendtoserver.push(ground);
            var sungeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1.875*50, 12*50, 12*50 );
            var sunmaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
        var sun = new THREE.Mesh( sungeometry, sunmaterial );
        sun.position.y=200;
        sun.position.z=-200;
        scene.add( sun );
        sendtoserver.push(sun);
        </script>

        <script>
            createtown=function(width){
                for(var i=-width/2+3.3;i<width/2-3.3;i+=3.3){
                    house(i,0,0,Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.radians(0));
                }
                for(var j=3.3;j<width-3.3;j+=3.3){
                    house(-j,0,-width/2,Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.radians(90));
                }
                for(var j=3.3;j<width-3.3;j+=3.3){
                    house(j,0,-width/2,Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.radians(270));
                }
                for(var j=-width/2+3.3;j<width/2-3.3;j+=3.3){
                    house(j,0,-width,Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.round(Math.random()*255),Math.radians(180));
                }
            }
            function changedirection(object){
            object.rotation.y=getrandomdirection();
            }
            var villager=function(){
            //edit this to draw villager
            var villagerfacegeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var facetexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "villagerface.png" );
            var villagerfacematerial=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: facetexture});
            materials=[
            villagerfacematerial,
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} )
            ]
            villagerface=new THREE.Mesh(villagerfacegeo,new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
            scene.add(villagerface);
            villagerface.position.z=10;
            villagerface.position.y=2;
            sendtoserver.push(villagerface);
            window.setInterval(function(){changedirection(villagerface);},5000);
            }
        </script>
        <!--Actual Program-->
        <script>
            createtown(99);
            //villager();
            camera.position.z = 5;
            camera.rotation.y=getrandomdirection();
            var stevefacegeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
            var stevefacetexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "villagerface.png" );
            var stevefacematerial=new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: stevefacetexture});
            materials=[
            stevefacematerial,
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} ),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} )
            ]
            steveface=new THREE.Mesh(stevefacegeo,new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
            scene.add(steveface);
            steveface.position.z=5;
            steveface.rotation.y=camera.rotation.y;
            sendtoserver.push(steveface);
            //Below this is non important camera controls
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server.php

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("Server.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("Server.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Server2.php

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("Server.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
foreach ($_POST[sendtoserver] as $value)
fwrite($myfile,$value);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

This site is online at rotatingcube.site88.net

Comment: You have a lot of code going on here. Can you reduce it down to the absolute minimum code to trigger the issue?

Comment: "echo array_values($_POST);" this in your server2.php will fire an "Array to string conversion" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it was an error with my server setup that I have gotten fixed already. However, there were problems in my php code you guys fixed. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code in server2.php file,

First, do not echo an array, that would give a conversion error. If you want to check what's inside an array use print_r(array) or var_dump(array) perhaps.

Second, you cannot write an array to a file directly, Loop through as per your array structure in $_POST['sendtoserver'] and then write the string in to the text file. You can use print_r($_POST['sendtoserver']); to see the array structure, you should be able to see the structure in the console(firebug/browser console) since its over Ajax.

Using foreach - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I don't think this would be the cause of the error they said in the post.

Comment: I have made this edit and it is still causing aw snap